Accurate estimate of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k^2+ck}$
I encountered a problem, where I  am interested in determining (or estimating) a series of the form
$$S = \sum_{k=0} ^\infty z^{k^2+ck},$$
while $z\in (0,1)$ and $c>0$. The most simple estimate I can think of is using $z^{k^2+ck}<z^{ck}$, which reduces the problem to the geometric series and we obtain
$$S < \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{ck}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (z^c)^k=\frac 1 {1-z^c}.$$
However, this estimate is rather inaccurate as $k^2$ is increasing much more rapidly than $ck$. So my question is, is there anyway to calculate $S$ directly, although I doubt that. Or is there any way to calculate / estimate
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k^2}.$$
Does such sequences have a special name?.

Update / Background: The problem above is just the abstraction of my original problem, to find an upper bound w.r.t. to the odd integer $N$ of
$$\sum_{|k|>\frac{N-1} 2} e^{-\frac{3\pi }{2 N}k^2}=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\frac{3\pi}{2N}\left(k+\frac{N+1}2\right)^2}=2e^{-\frac{3 \pi (N+1)^2}{8N}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k^2+(N+1)k},$$
for $z=e^{-\frac{3\pi}{2N}}$. So, we can bound the  sum on the right by
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{ k^2}&=-i\int_{i-\infty}^{i+\infty}e^{-  \frac{3   \pi  u^2}{2N}}\cot( \pi u) du\\
&\leq e^{\frac{3\pi}{2N}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{3\pi u^2}{2N}}|\cot(\pi(i+u)|du\\
&\leq 1.004\; e^{\frac{3\pi}{2N}} \int _{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{3\pi u^2}{2N}}
du\\
&=1.004\; e^{\frac{3\pi}{2N}} \sqrt{\tfrac{2N}3}, \end{align*}
while the integral representation is given through the theta function and the factor 1.004, is a  numerical upper bound of the cotanges on the horizontal line $u\mapsto (u+i)\pi)$.
However, numerical test suggest that this estimate is rather inaccurate. For $N = 100001$ we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k^2+(N+1)k}\approx 1.009$$
and
$$ 1.004\; e^{\frac{3\pi}{2N}} \sqrt{\tfrac{2N}3}\approx 259.25.$$
Does anyone have better suggestions?

Read about theta function

Moreover you can write $k^2 + ck = (k + c/2)^2 - c^2/4$ which might help by reindexing if $c$ is an even integer.

If $c>0$ and $0<z<1$, then
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {z^{k^2  + ck} } & \le 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\int_{k - 1}^k {z^{t^2  + ct} \,{\rm d}t} }  = 1 + \int_0^{ + \infty } {z^{t^2  + ct} \,{\rm d}t} \\ &
 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{\log (1/z)}}} z^{ - \frac{{c^2 }}{4}} \operatorname{erfc}\left( {\frac{c}{2}\sqrt {\log (1/z)} } \right).
\end{align*}
Here $\text{erfc}$ is the complementary error function. This is further bounded from above by
$$
1 - \frac{1}{{c\log z}},
$$
which is particularly useful near $z=1$. This yields
$$
\sum\limits_{\left| k \right| > \frac{{N - 1}}{2}} {{\rm e}^{ - \frac{{3\pi }}{{2N}}k^2 } }  \le 2\,{\rm e}^{ - \frac{{3\pi }}{{2N}}\left(\frac{N + 1}{2}\right)^2 } \left( {1 + \frac{{2N}}{{3\pi (N + 1)}}} \right)
$$
for your original problem.

Since we know that
$$\int z^{k^2+ck}\,dk=\frac 12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\log (z)}}\,\,z^{-\frac{c^2}{4}}\,\, \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{2} (c+2 k)
   \sqrt{\log (z)}\right)$$
$$\int_{0}^\infty z^{k^2+ck}\,dk =\frac 12 \sqrt{-\frac{\pi}{\log (z)}}\,\,z^{-\frac{c^2}{4}}\,\, \text{erfc}\left(\frac{c}{2} \sqrt{-\log (z)}\right)$$ I think that a Euler-MacLaurin summation could be of interest.
Limited to its simplest form (using $L=\log(z)$
$$S = \sum_{k=0} ^\infty z^{k^2+ck}=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\,
   z^{-\frac{c^2}{4}}}{\sqrt{-L}}\right)-\frac{F\left(\frac{c}{2} \sqrt{L}\right)}{\sqrt{L}}-\frac{c L}{12}\sum_{i=0}^6 a_i\,L^i$$ where the  coefficients are
$$\left\{1,-\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{42}-\frac{c^2}{60},\frac{c^2}{126
   }-\frac{1}{120},\frac{c^2 \left(2
   c^2-21\right)}{5040},-\frac{c^4}{2400},-\frac{c^6}{100800}\right\}$$
Notice that $F(.)$ is Dawson function which also write
$$F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\,  e^{-x^2} \,\,\text{erfi}(x)$$
Trying for $c=1$ and $z=\frac 12$, this gives $1.265825028$ while the summation gives $1.265870095$
